# Have a query that displays all results twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query that returns all rows twice.
Using a union isn't possible (as it has to become an indexed view).

Anybody know how to do it?

(So this I can't do:)

```
select * from tags
union all
select * from tags
```

Comment: I didn't initially see the indexed view requirement :( had to remove my answer. What is it you are really trying to do? Why the strong need to index all your rows twice?

Comment: Well I join multiple tables upon the base table, so that each result will be unique of the two.

Comment: However now i see that using union is probably the only how that wuold be possible :(.

Comment: Why do you need an indexed view for this? Is the index on the underlying table not sufficient? I see a lot of people make leaps of faith that an indexed view will magically improve the performance, and I don't know where this comes from. This model does not appear to me that it will benefit from an indexed view at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to create another table, you might get away with this:

```
create table duplicator (id int)
insert into duplicator values (1),(2)
go
create view dups with schemabinding 
as
   select tags.column1, tags.column2, ... , duplicator.id
     from dbo.tags
    cross join dbo.duplicator
go
create unique clustered index ix_dups on dups(tags.PK, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp(idx) as (
    select 1 as idx union select 2 as idx
)
select * from yourtable cross join temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an indexed view with a union (or a CTE, or a cross join to itself, etc). But you could do something like this (I'm making assumptions about column names and the primary key):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.TagsView1
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.tags;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.TagsView(col1);
```

Now create a view that performs a union against that:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.TagsView2
AS
   SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.TagsView1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.TagsView1;
GO
```

This satisfies your requirement to some degree, but I still find the requirement suspect. Unless you can explain exactly why you think this should be an indexed view. If the answer is "because it will be faster" then the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table to hold the number of rows to duplicate and then do a cross join against it:

```
DECLARE @tblOrig table (PK int, fruitName varchar(20));
insert @tblOrig values (1, 'Apple');
insert @tblOrig values (2, 'Banana');
insert @tblOrig values (3, 'Pear');

DECLARE @tblDup table (DuplicateNumber int);
insert @tblDup values (1);
insert @tblDup values (2);

select t1.*
from @tblOrig t1
cross join @tblDup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_number() over (order by columnnamehere), *
from
(
select * from tags 
union all
select * From tags 
) a
```